# ufw deny IP traffic

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have the following entry which keeps returning in my mailserver logs:

> [11/Sep/2017 16:38:35] Message from IP address 52.187.171.228, sender
>    temporarily
>   rejected: sender domain does not resolve

So I thought it would be a good idea to block the IP and ran:

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 52.187.171.228 to any
```

But apparently this doesn't work because the logs keep coming.

[image: uwf status command]

Is this the correct approach?